# Parametrable randon from a list generated

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to implant a method that returns a list of items from a DataBase done via SQLite.
The table is simple (ID, intitule "text",comment).

I wrote a method that selects my questions and puts them in a listview:

```
public ArrayList getList(){
    ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();
    Random ran = new Random();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " +KEY_INTITULE+ " from " +TABLE_QUESTION,null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while(c.isAfterLast()==false){
            String t1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INTITULE));
            lst.add(t1);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return lst;
}
```

I want to give the user the possibility to choose how much INTITULE the user wants to display, getting this number of random items.
If s/he chooses 3, /she gets 3 randomly choosen items.

I also tried to do it like this, but it doesn't work

```
int size = lst.size();
        int tmp=-1;
        int rnd;
       String randomID = new String();
        ArrayList  <String> listrand = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j=0;j<param;j++){
            rnd = rand.nextInt(size)-1;
            if(rnd!=tmp){
                randomID =lst.add(rand);
                listrand.add(randomID);
               // tmp!=rnd;

            }
        }
        return listrand;
    }
```

Comment: show complete code of second snippet , seems like `lst` is empty

Comment: lst isn't empty, it contains the list of all INTITULE and they're displayed in the app

Comment: show complete code , and before doing that , do some debugging

Answer (score 0):

It worked finally, I had only to use Order by in sql

int param;

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " +KEY_QUESTION+ " from " +TABLE_QUESTION+ " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " +param+ ,null);
```